# Why does my bool function returning true result in read access violation?

Tags: c++, memory, binary-search-tree, unique-ptr, access-violation

I am currently writing a BST using unique_ptr. I have boolean function (remove) to remove data that then calls a recursive function (removeNode, which returns a bool) to find the node and remove it. However, sometimes when the remove function is returning true, it throws a read-access violation in the memory library. I do not know enough about how return works in a function to fully understand what is happening. This issue has nothing to do with returning the bool. It is when the function then tries to return the "this" object that called the function that the access violation occurs.

I have established breakpoints and the recursive function returns just fine. It returns true. I have placed in all caps the line where this error occurs because I could not figure out how to highlight it.

Here is the remove function that calls the recursive function

```
virtual bool removeNode(const T& data)
{
   if (root == nullptr) return false;
   if (data < root->data)
   {
    return removeNode(root->lhChild, root, false, data);
   }
   else if (data > root->data)
   {
    return removeNode(root->rhChild, root, true, data);
   }
   else if (data == root->data)
   {
    if (isLeaf(root))
    {
       root.reset(nullptr);
       --szTree;
       return true;
    }
    else if ((root->lhChild != nullptr) && (root->rhChild != nullptr))
    {
       std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> temp(root->lhChild.get());
       while (temp->rhChild != nullptr)
       {
          temp.reset(temp->rhChild.get());
       }
       root->data = temp->data;
       bool rtn = removeNode(root->lhChild, root, false, temp->data);
       RETURN TRUE;
    }
    else if (root->lhChild != nullptr)
    {
       root->data = root->lhChild->data;
       return removeNode(root->lhChild, root, false, root->data);
    }
    else
    {
       root->data = root->rhChild->data;
       return removeNode(root->rhChild, root, false, root->data);
    }
   }
}
```

Here is the recursive function:

```
bool removeNode(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>& n, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>& p, bool isRh, T data)
{
   if (n == nullptr) return false;
   else if (n->data == data)
   {
    if (isLeaf(n))
    {
       n.reset(nullptr);
       if (isRh) p->rhChild.reset(nullptr);
       else p->lhChild.reset(nullptr);
       --szTree;
       return true;
    }
    else if ((n->lhChild != nullptr) && (n->rhChild != nullptr))
    {
       std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> temp(n->lhChild.get());
       while (temp->rhChild != nullptr)
       {
        temp.reset(temp->rhChild.get());
       }
       n->data = temp->data;
       return removeNode(n->lhChild, n, false, temp->data);
    }
    else if (n->lhChild != nullptr)
    {
       p->lhChild = std::move(n->lhChild);
       --szTree;
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       p->rhChild = std::move(n->rhChild);
       --szTree;
       return true;
    }
   }
   else if (data < n->data) return removeNode(n->lhChild, n, false, data);
   else return removeNode(n->rhChild, n, true, data);
}
```

If it helps here is where the error occurs in memory

```
_NODISCARD pointer get() const noexcept { // return pointer to object
        return this->_Myptr();
    }
```

The error reads:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Unique_ptr_base<Node<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::default_delete<Node<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Myptr(...) returned 0xDDDDDDFD. occurred
```

It should return true like normal but for some reason it is having trouble returning the object that called the function. Due to my limited knowledge of what is happening when the function returns I do not even really know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the destructor of one of the `unique_ptr`s is causing an access violation.

This is because you are deleting an object more than once. When a unique_ptr is destroyed, it also deletes the object it points to. Also, calling `reset` on a unique_ptr deletes the object it was previously pointing to.

So when you do

```
while (temp->rhChild != nullptr)
{
    temp.reset(temp->rhChild.get());
}
```

you are in fact deleting all these nodes that are still in the tree, after you look at them. But also, the unique_ptr (presumably) in the tree is still pointing to those deleted nodes. So you have problems with dangling pointers.

Comment: This was amazing advice. I changed temp to a regular pointer and it fixed the problem